# Get user by Id asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository

I'm new to asp.net and I try to build my first website. I'm implementing repositories and I need how to find user by `id`. Here is my repository class for user:

```
public class UserRepository
{

    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public ApplicationUser GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(ApplicationUser => ApplicationUser.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue with the code you've posted. However, the default in Identity is that IdentityUser will have a *string* PK, so unless you've utilized the generic classes to make the key an int, that might be your issue. That said, don't create repositories like this. You're just shooting yourself in the foot. See: http://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 2):

[assuming your solution uses microsoft identity, and user is logged in]

```
ApplicationDbContext mycontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
UserStore<ApplicationUser> mystore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(mycontext);
ApplicationUserManager userMgr = new ApplicationUserManager(mystore);
var _user = userMgr.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

Then you can easily get access to the user object and all its properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Find(id)` to retrieve a entity using its primary key.

```
public ApplicationUser GetUserById(int id)
{
    return _db.Users.Find(id);
}
```